# each and alert if all is ok

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('input').each(function(){
var id =  $(this).attr('id');
var class =  $(this).attr('class');
var val = $(this).val();

if(val.length == 0){
  alert('Error');
  return false;
}

//HERE STOP UNTIL ALL IS OK

var data = '?id=' + id + '&class=' + class + '&val=' + val;
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});


})
```

How to make this? I would like use $.ajax only if all input have length > 0.

for example if i have input:

```
1: [aaa]
2: [asad]
3: []
4: [sdfs]
```

then

```
1: - no error and send with ajax
2: - no error and send with ajax
3: - error  and not send with - ajax previous return false
4: - stop script
```

In this example should be:

```
1: - no error - add to array and wait - not send with ajax
2: - no error - add to array and wait - not send with ajax
3: - error stop script - any data not send with ajax.
```

I would like send ajax only if all values are ok. How can i make it?

Comment: Assuming no errors, are you wanting to send four ajax requests, one for each input, or a single ajax request with the data from all inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to iterate twice, and use an indicator/flag variable to keep track of whether any validation failed:

```
var valid = true;
$('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
      alert('Error');
      valid = false;
      return false;
    }
});

if(valid)
    $('input').each(function(){
        var id =  $(this).attr('id');
        var class =  $(this).attr('class');
        var val = $(this).val();

        var data = '?id=' + id + '&class=' + class + '&val=' + val;
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data: data,
          success: success,
          dataType: dataType
        });
    });
```

Comment: You could make it a little more efficient by caching the jQuery object, using `var $inputs = $('input')`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Is that likely to make a difference? Given that the intent here is to launch a whole bunch of AJAX requests, I figured the overhead of finding `input` elements would be trivial by comparison. Did I figure wrongly?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. And caching would've made the answer more complicated than it needed to be by dealing with a side-issue. I just figure that in a general sense caching is a good habit to get into because inevitably similar code will end up somewhere that it does matter (like in an intensive loop), but here it would've been an unhelpful distraction.

Comment: Just a word of caution using `var class` could cause issues in some browsers where `class` is a keyword.